# Remote Debugging doesnt work

Tags: .net, tridion, templating, tridion-2011

After setting up remote debugging by following [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12210711/tridion-template-builder-and-visual-studio-debugging), we were able to locate and attach the Template Builder Process ID in Visual studio 2008.

However we are still not able to debug. After creating a breakpoint, we attach the Template builder process for debugging. When we run the compound template from Template builder, the process executes without stopping at breakpoint.

The code is running fine, but we are not able to debug.

Anything we missed?

Comment: Do the breakpoints show up normally or are they disabled with the message that the debug symbols haven't been loaded?

Answer (score 4):

If it is Template Builder you should attach to the Template Debugging host, while running your  template in template builder, also check you dont have a version of your dll in the GAC

Answer (score 0):

Have you started the remote debug application (like Visual Studio 2010 Remote Debugger (x64)) on Tridion server?

Comment: yes, that is started. Hence I am able to get the process ID of template builder.

Comment: have you set the Qualifier name as tridion server name in Attach to Process in VS? Because some its not connected with tridion

Comment: Now in that case, you should re-chcek the Remote Debugging Monitor steps and your machine name should be come in the remote debugging monitor,
Be sure to run this executable as the user who is running Visual Studio on the client machine. You can do this, for example, from the Windows command line prompt using the runas command. The user must be a local administrator on the Content Manager server machine.

Answer (score 0):

Now days are gone with connecting to remote debugger host.

We have a new facility to debug all the tridion templates locally without connecting to remote debugger host which is called as **"TcmDebugger"**.

**[SDL Tridion Content Manager .NET Templating Debugger](https://code.google.com/p/tcmdebugger/)**

For more details, refer **[How to debug Tridion Templates without connecting to TcmTemplateDebugHost.exe](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/4414/how-to-debug-tridion-templates-without-connecting-to-tcmtemplatedebughost-exe)**